# How to hide import lines in python?

Tags: python

When i am executing Selenium tests, there are hundreds of `import` lines in `main.py`.

What is the best way to hide them?

Edit：

This problem arises because I did not use an IDE with auto-hide functionality. It now appears that there is only one way to slove it.
Move all imports to another file, like the following answers.

Comment: Why you want to hide those `import ` >

Comment: It has hundreds of lines that are inconvenient to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to mess with your source code in any way to achieve this. The only way on the code level I can think of is moving all imports into a different file, let's say `foo.py` and do `from foo import *`, but I don't recommend this.

Instead, simply use an IDE that can do that for you when looking at your sourcecode. For example I am using pycharm and it can do this:

[image: Pycharm screenshot showing collapsed imports]

when there are a lot of imports, which is much more convenient to read.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just because I use vim in GUI-less operating systems, I see hundreds of lines of imports, and this creates this strange problem.